# Adding items to an object array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array like this:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I have an array of objects like this:

```
obj = [{"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M"},
       {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F"},
       {"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F"},
       {"Name":"XYZ","Age":30,"Gender":"F"}]
```

I need to push each element of the data array into each object of the array. My expected output is this:

```
obj = [{"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M", "Data":1}, 
       {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F", "Data":2}, 
       {"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F", "Data":3}, 
       {"Name":"XYZ","Age":30,"Gender":"F", "Data":4}]
```

I tried like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
   obj.push({data:data[i])
}
```

But that gave an incorrect result like this:

```
obj = [{"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M"},
       {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F"}, 
       {"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F"},
       {"Name":"XYZ","Age":30,"Gender":"F"}, 
       {"Data":1},{"Data":2},{"Data":3},{"Data":4}]
```

I understand that this is because I am not iterating through array of object before pushing the items into it. But I am unable to iterate through data as well as obj together. Please help me solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I am unable to iterate through data as well as obj together*" really? `for(let i =0; i < data.length; i++) { const d = data[i]; const o = obj[i]; }`

Comment: `push()` is for adding new elements to an array, not for modifying elements that are already in an array.

Comment: `obj[i].data = data[i]`

Comment: As point out by @Barmar's comment above, you can have a look ```array.map()```, something like ```const output = obj.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, Data: data[i] }));```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the length of the 2 arrays are the same:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj[i].Data = data[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways in achieving the expected output.
Here is one of the ways, Loop through the array using `Array.map` and destructuring

```js
const data = [{"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M"}, {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F"},{"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F"},{"Name":"XYZ","Age":30,"Gender":"F"}];
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const formattedData = (data, array) => data.map((obj, i) => (  
  {
    ...obj,
    Data: array[i]
  }
));

console.log(formattedData(data, array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved by a spread operator. Please have a look as following codes.

```js
obj = [{"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M"},
       {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F"},
       {"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F"},
       {"Name":"XYZ","Age":30,"Gender":"F"}]
data = [1,2,3,4,5]

newObj = obj.map((item, i)=>({...item, Data: data[i]}));
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = obj.map((e,i) => ({...e, "Data":data[i]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

const data = [{"Name":"ABC","Age":25,"Gender":"M"}, {"Name":"DEF","Age":32,"Gender":"F"},{"Name":"PQR","Age":30,"Gender":"F"},{"Name":"XYZ","Age":30,"Gender":"F"}];
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Few things to consider here is we need new object where the length remains same as data and array.
With the help of map function , we can get eachData and index of the eachData and we can mutate the object by adding `Data` in this case.

We need to add closing bracket as *Rest parameter must be last formal parameter* forgetting which would throw syntax error for the same

const formattedData = (data,array) => data.map((eachData,i)=> ({...eachData,Data:array[i]}))